# Greek Dvorak keyboard layout

Tags: macos, layout, keyboard, dvorak

Greetings from Greece :D

In my effort to learn English Dvorak layout, which I liked btw, i tried to find a Greek Dvorak layout. I tried Ukelele (mac user), to create a layout from scratch since there are no any available online. The problem is with a single Greek Character/symbol,tone.

In it's single format is just this: ΄ 
a character that i can assign on Ukelele and works fine.

But that's the part i can't really fix.

This character is being combined with the vowels of the alphabet when is needed so the result i normally get is this: ά (or, ό, ή, έ etc etc).

Ukelele can't really recognize this parameter and I can't assign the tone on the letters so I get this result instead: ΄α, ΄ο, etc etc.

Any possible solutions?

thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you need to do is create a "dead key" state. You can create one in Ukelele with the "Create" button in the tool bar.

You might be interested in a [lightly custom layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rvuw.png) that I created by applying the results of a paper I found online that suggested the creation of a new greek keyboard layout (called ΝΕΠ) and the Dvorak layout.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ' | , | . | π | υ | φ | γ | δ | ρ | λ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| α | ο | ε | ς | ι | ΄ | η | τ | ν | σ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ; | ψ | ξ | κ | χ | β | μ | θ | ω | ζ |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```